# Old messages were removed by Facebook for being sent by a blocked app

Tags: facebook

I dug back through a pretty old conversation from a time when 3rd party messengers were allowed. Back then I used a 3rd party messaging app, and now I need to see the messages as they are really important, (not legal stuff,) but they are just a yellow box that says "This message was removed because the app it's being sent from is blocked from sending messages." Is there a way to get them back?

[image]

Comment: can you tell me exacctly,after how much time this comes after sending or receiving message?

Comment: Immediately after i refresh the page

Comment: This isn't programming related, is it? You shoud contact Facebook.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. For Facebook end user support, please go check their Help section. / The “download all your data” functionality Facebook offers might(!) contain those message too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming or software development.